# Cannot find Three.Js Meshline

Tags: three.js

I was wondering if there was a three.js supported of Three.Meshline out there.

There were a few but outdated over 2-3 years ago and no longer supported. Let me know if there is anything out there for creating curves from data points for trajectories of a particle in an animation.

Comment: Try it with: https://docs.lume.io/three-meshline/